# variable names are not populating from .env in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm trying to populate this nginx.conf.template file with some variables from an .env file in my project. My .env is located in the same directory with my docker-compose.yml.

Here is my nginx.conf.template:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $DOCKER_DOMAIN_NAMES;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name $events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $DOCKER_DOMAIN_NAMES;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name $DOCKER_SERVER_NAMES;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH}/chain.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://app:3000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
};

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH}/chain.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://app:3000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}
```

I check the container `docker exec -it nginx_container sh`
I see that the variable names like `$DOCKER_SERVER_NAMES` are still there instead of the string values.

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - DOMAIN_NAMES=${DOCKER_DOMAIN_NAMES}
      - CERTIFICATION_EMAIL=${DOCKER_CERTIFICATION_EMAIL}
      - DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH=${DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH}
    volumes:
      - ./ssl-dhparams.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf.template:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template:ro
      - ./nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf:/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:ro
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - app
```

My variables seem to work in other parts, but for some reason I can't get them to work in the confg.template file.

My project structure:

```
project/
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── .env
└── nginx/
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── nginx.conf.template
    └── myshellscript.sh
```

for example myshellscript.sh will have something `/etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH/fullchain.pem` and this it comes out in the container as expected `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem` so I'm not sure what's the problem with these other variables. How can I make it dynamic in the template file?

Comment: `for some reason I can't get them to work in the confg.template` Why should they work there in the first place? Did you read that in any documentation? I do not understand - what program should be responsible for templating the config templating?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, it's part of nginx. it's one of the volumes ``./nginx/nginx.conf.template:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template:ro``. The variables work inside my shell script which is also in the container and runs inside it, but the variables in my nginx.conf.template file are still showing as ``$DOCKER_DOMAIN_NAMES`` instead of the value.

Comment: `it's part of nginx` I do not understand, can you post a link stating that nginx interpolates environment variables in configuration files? I do not think that is true and I think `.template` files are just ignored by nginx. `the variables in my nginx.conf.template file are still showing as` Right, _why_ would you expect otherwise? There is nothing that would interpolate environment variables in that file.

Comment: no, not nginx. docker should be replacing this variable ``$DOCKER_DOMAIN_NAMES`` with the value in the .env file, but that's not happening. It's happening inside ``myshellscript.sh``, but not in the ``nginx.conf.template`` file. I have no idea why.  For example ``myshellscript.sh`` contains this line in it ``echo "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH/fullchain.pem"`` which docker correctly translate into ``echo "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem"``.

Comment: Sorry, that is just false. Docker does not replace any variables in mounted files. `or example myshellscript.sh contains this line in it` Yes, _the shell_ process when it is executing your script inside the container interpolates environment variables, like it does anywhere else.

Comment: @KamilCuk oh, I see ``myshellscript.sh`` has the same line inside of it ``echo "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOCKER_DOMAIN_PATH/fullchain.pem"`` when I view in the contianer and now I see it's the same inside (meaning it has the variable name not the value), but how does it actually come out the right way when I see my nginx container running the shell script it will output the value instead of the variable name ``nginx_1    | /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> docker should be replacing this variable $DOCKER_DOMAIN_NAMES with the value in the .env file

No, docker does not interpolate environment variables anywhere. Docker also has no possibility of affecting mounted files content.

If any, `docker-compose` when parsing a `docker-compose.yml` interpolates the environment variables *only in that file* and also with a slightly different syntax than shell, as documented https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/ .

> How can I make it dynamic in the template file?

You have to write code that will do that. The simplest is `envsubst` if it is available in your image, and add that to `entrypoint` of your image.

Comment: thank you, I see where my error was. I had this ``envsubst "$SERVER_NAMES $DOMAIN_PATH" < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.prod.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`` but the $ symbol should have been escaped **\$** in my double quotes like this ``envsubst "\$SERVER_NAMES \$DOMAIN_PATH" < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.prod.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.``